# SQL Server equivalent of MySQL Extract(hour_second)

Tags: sql-server-2012

Hope you can help...  I'm converting a stored procedure from MySQL to SQL Server 2012 and I've came across a small issue.  The MySQL sp has the following code:

`SET @hrsecA = EXTRACT(HOUR_SECOND FROM (startDate + INTERVAL startTime HOUR_SECOND));`

I'm trying to find what the SQL Server equivalent of this is...  I thought using DATEPART would be the way to go, but can't seem to see an option in DATEPART that lets me select HOUR_SECOND.

Hope you can help.

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For year you may use
DATEPART(yyyy,OrderDate)

And for second, use

Select NmbrSeconds=
Cast(Left(Duration,Charindex('minutes',Duration)-1) As Int) * 60 +
Cast(Substring(Duration,Charindex('minutes',Duration)+8,2) As Int)